# IE7 z-index and stacking contexts -- z-index works everywhere but IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

So I came up with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sdES/2/ that produces some interesting results.

In any browser other than IE7, the page renders with the "modal" element overlaid on top of everything else:
[image: Chrome screenshot]

However in IE7, the z-indexes don't seem to work as they do elsewhere:
[image: IE7 screenshot]

The way I understand IE7 and z-indexes is that it creates a new stacking index for every element with "position" set. But all the elements I'm dealing with here have position set; it's my understanding that they should be in the same stacking context and thus the backdrop(with z-index 1040) should appear behind the modal(with z-index 1050)... but it's clearly not happening with IE7.

Any thoughts? I've tried shifting things all over the DOM, applying positions and z-indexes everywhere and I can't make IE7 happy.

Comment: You would have to move `.modal` to the bottom of `.wrapper` in your html if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a z-index of 1200 to the `.module` div surrounding the modal fixes the issue in IE7.